# Any documentation Available for Microsoft Office365 Exchange development in .net

Tags: office365, office365-apps

i am search the sample code for Microsoft Office 365 Exchange but not get please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend...

API (they are in preview release): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892%28v=office.15%29.aspx

And on the same MSDN page, link to code samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769089%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: above all link provide Mail REST API i am using a Microsoft Office 365 Exchange (dll) so please share the link.

Comment: No, the links above talk about all Office 365 APIs: Mail, Calendar, Contacts, Files, etc. What do you want exactly to do?

Comment: But above link is only a REST Api example.
i have sample code using Microsoft Office 365 Exchange (dll)

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the place for what you are looking for. And it is still unclear.
The samples link I gave you contains Code samples using Office365 dll, but you do not seem to understand how to use a DLL